# Folder Upload ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I currently have a button which enables the user to choose 1 or more files but I would like to implement another button that functions as a folder upload.

The user selects a folder and all the files in the folder will be uploaded. Is this possible to do? I haven't been able to find any native solutions.

Comment: Refer https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/306/working-with-zip-files-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: You can't upload a whole folder through a HTML form just by selecting it no. The user would have to zip the contents into a zip file first. Then you can upload the zip file (because it's a file, not a folder).